# 404 Error Handling in Cached Networked Images

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

So i wanted to create a card with an image. I fetched the data and stored it in my **news map** with key **urlToImage** as my image url. Its working all fine but when a url such as

> https://i-invdn-com.investing.com/news/https://i-invdn-com.investing.com/akapi-images/800x450/59149e84fbd2b771f1b6adea95d99dd6_w_800_h_450.jpg

where resource isn't found (404 error).
My app crashes.

here is the log image of the error:

error log

[image: error log]

I'm new to flutter and dart so can someone help me learn how to handle this case?

This is my CachedNetworkImage widget.

```
          CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: news['urlToImage'] ?? NewsConstants.errorImage,
            progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, downloadProgress) =>
                CircularProgressIndicator(value: downloadProgress.progress),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
          )
```

I have tried using error widget but it doesn't help either

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app & yes the link return 404

Comment: the error still persists after it.

Comment: I've tested on web, it is working , can you create a separate widget and just test this part

Comment: web_helper.dart is throwing error

Comment: can you test it by running on release mode

Comment: Really sorry about it but I'm still learning flutter can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: try `flutter run -d c --release `

Comment: It is showing Release mode is not supported by iPhone 14 Pro Max. which emulator should i use?

Comment: which IDE you are using

Comment: vs code + ios simulator

Comment: try https://dartcode.org/docs/running-flutter-apps-in-profile-or-release-modes/

Comment: let me try it will ping you

Answer (score 0):

I think that the url is broken. It looks like url String is created from 2 separate urls. Probably you will need to remove starting part of it (https://i-dndvn-com.investing.com/news/)

> https://i-dndvn-com.investing.com/news/https://i-invdn.invetinga.com/akapi..

Comment: yeah but it is provided by api so how can i validate they can change dynamically

Comment: Are you sure that API returns the wrong url ?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to copy this url you are using "https://i-invdn-com.investing.com/news/https://i-invdn-com.investing.com/akapi-images/800x450/59149e84fbd2b771f1b6adea95d99dd6_w_800_h_450.jpg" But it gave 404 back because there was no picture.

But when I used "https://i-invdn-com.investing.com/akapi-images/800x450/59149e84fbd2b771f1b6adea95d99dd6_w_800_h_450.jpg" everything was fine.

If you always pull the saddle message from the same URL then use it like news['urlToImage'].toString().substring(39)

```
CachedNetworkImage(
            imageUrl: news['urlToImage'].toString().substring(39) 
?? 
NewsConstants.errorImage,
            progressIndicatorBuilder: (context, url, 
downloadProgress) =>
                CircularProgressIndicator(value: 
downloadProgress.progress),
            errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const 
Icon(Icons.error),
          )
```

Comment: nah actually the URLs are dynamically changing provided by NewsAPI

Comment: Currently, if you use the code I wrote above, the current problem will disappear.

Comment: yea i get that but still how can i validate 404 errors in general

Comment: Your approach is wrong. You can't type any URL and expect an image from there. You must make sure that the URL you use is for the image. Either the image must come or NULL. Try to get the APIs you want to use. In this case, everything will be conveniently written in the documentation.